# How can I prevent a search & filter script from using image urls in the result?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table on one of my webpages that can be filtered using a search bar.

The script works pretty much as intended but for one problem.

Each row of the table contains an image of a flag. All of these images were uploaded to my site in 2018. This means if a user searches for 2018 the table remains unfiltered because the script is using the 2018 from the image src url in the results.

Is it possible for me to have the script ignore those image urls?

If you search for 2018 in the search bar on WEBSITE REMOVED you'll see my issue. Search for others years and you'll see that it works fine.

The script I'm using is:

```
SCRIPT REMOVED
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `textContent` of the table cell, you'll see it includes the URL.

[image]

Your solution is just to be more specific about you want. Maybe

```
rows[0].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].textContent
```

[image]

Comment: Your response is exactly what I'm looking for. In the example given I only want Britain to be a potential result not the image url. I am new to javascipt though so where in my script do I add your solution?

Comment: In place of the line where you're doing:
`var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();`

Comment: Willis, thank you! I was adding (); to the end of your solution. I should have realised there was a reason you didn't use it. Many thanks! I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer but I very much appreciate it. Cheers.